# Angularjs performance - jqLiteInheritedData

Tags: performance, angularjs, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, jqlite

I am using Angular.js on my mobile app (using a Webview).

While running timeline to monitor performance I found a ~700ms for "Parse HTML". A deeper look found that the responsible method ("Function call") for this (see screenshot) is "jqLiteInheritedData":

[image]

Googling / debugging this did not provide me additional data... 
I would love some direction on what is the purpose of this method and how could I avoid this performance bottleneck.

**EDIT**:
After a little debugging I noticed that this method is called during the "createEventHandler" / "eventHandler" methods.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?